# DoCmd.OutputTo + With a SQL Command + VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Hey everyone i did some research online but i couldn't get a solution,  hopefully someone here can help. My go is to place a sql statement to a  DoCmd.OutputTo

for example

```
      Set tempSql= CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM SpecialEvent WHERE [HG_ID] = " & HG_ID & ";")

      DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "tempSql", acFormatXLS, strDir + "try.xls", 0
```

If anyone can guide me to building this approach, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the sql of a query to the output sql and use the query name in DoCmd.OutputTo

```
tempSql= "SELECT * FROM SpecialEvent WHERE [HG_ID] = " & HG_ID

If IsNull(DLookup("name", "msysobjects", "name='query1'")) Then
    CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef "Query1", tempSql 
Else
    CurrentDB.QueryDefs("Query1").SQL = TempSQL
End If


DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "Query1", acFormatXLS, strDir & "try.xls", 0
```

Note that the concatenator is & in VBA, not +

The plus sign can be used to concatenate, but it needs great care because of the way it works with nulls.

Comment: Thank you this worked great, for other users that look at this if you require to delete the the query in the end like i did just add DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "Query1"